# What is a *materialized* double?

Tags: c#

Checked a number of places, but can't find a coherent concise definition of materialize in the sense of a "materialized system.double type"  -- what is the word materialized signifying?

Comment: What's the context? In the context of **Entity Framework**, A *"materialized"* value is a value obtained from a Data Store (database) and stored into an Entity's property (a .Net class with properties).

Comment: @HighCore I agree, this is only mention I can find of the word "materialized" used within the context of C#, is with Entity Framework.

Comment: @Jesse Checked a few places myself and SO references it in the context of Entity Framework a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fancy way of saying "deserialized".  Read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about EF which doesn't actually give a definition but it uses the word enough to clarify things through it's context such as...

> Query results are materialized into objects that the Entity Framework manages.